# Panels with 4 or more columns

Tags: panels

Is it possible to create a panel with 4 or more columns? The sample templates in the Panel module only go as far as 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes If panel setting restrict you to go beyond 3 column you can place panels in panels.

Comment: How stupid of me, of course. Sorry to have wasted your time, guys.

Answer (score 2):

You could also define your own 4-column panel. There are instructions here: [Panels 3: Creating a custom layout in your theme](http://drupal.org/node/495654), and a more specific tutorial available here: [Creating a four column layout for Panels 3 in Drupal 7](http://miss-hana.com/creating-a-custom-layout-for-panels-3-in-drupal-7/).

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many regions as you which and use CSS/HTML to place them where you want. You have to define the regions in the planel declaration to make it work.